# Why does dont you have to #include<vector>, if you already include using name space std?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I have been learning about object orientated computing and in particular iterators and standard template libraries etc.

I don't quite seem to understand why if you write

```
std:vector<int> - //blah, a vector is created.
```

However, in some cases you need to write

```
#include <vector> //to include vector library
```

Why is this? 
Does the standard library where we usually write "using namespace std" - already include the vector library?

When I remove the definition file #include, then the computer cannot recognize my vector variables.

However, I have seen in some cases that many people have used the vector function without actually declaring it by using std::vector???

```
std::vector<int>::iterator pos;
std::vector<int>coll;
```

this is the code other people use and it seems to work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<int>::iterator pos;
vector<int>coll;
}
```

// this works for me, but I want to understand why this one works and the other one doesn't.

Comment: `using namespace std; // this is a using directive telling the compiler to check the std namespace when resolving identifiers with no prefix` -- https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/naming-conflicts-and-the-std-namespace/

Comment: In *all* cases you need to use `#include <vector>`, not just because it doesn't compile. Another header might include it, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: `std:vector<int>` one semi-colon is a `label`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `using namespace std;` directive just says "For anything in the `std` namespace *that I know about*, you can leave off the `std::` prefix". But without the `#include <vector>` (directly or indirectly via some other `#include`), the compiler has no idea `std::vector` exists in the first place. The reason why some code samples work without the include is that they included some *other* header which in turn includes `<vector>`. If they didn't do that, then there is no definition of `std::vector`, and the code fails with undefined types. `<vector>` must be included, but indirect inclusion via some *other* include is enough (that said, you should always `#include` it directly if you're using `std::vector`, to avoid potential header changes, or differences between implementations, breaking compilation).

Headers give you the declarations (and in some cases, definitions) of various classes and APIs; the `using namespace` declaration just removes the need to explicitly qualify your references to them with a namespace prefix.

The reason you're still required to perform the `#include`s is about deconfliction of declarations (you don't want to just include every possible include file, because some of them might have conflicting definitions of certain names), and compilation performance (`#include`ing the world means many kilobytes, if not megabytes, of additional code to compile, the vast majority of which you won't actually use; limiting it to the headers you actually need means less disk I/O, lower memory and lower CPU time to perform compilation).

For future reference, "where we usually write 'using namespace std;'" indicates you've been taught bad habits. `using namespace std;` [is frowned upon in production code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696).

Comment: Why do you mean "for anything that I know"?

Comment: actually i understand what your saying now! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @HasanHussaini: "I" in this case is referring to the compiler; the directive says "anything the compiler knows in about `std` need not be qualified with `std` by the programmer". I was speaking somewhat informally using "I" and "you", sorry if that confused.

Comment: This only answers half the question. Why don't the other code samples need the include?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I mentioned that in passing when I said "without the `#include <vector>` (directly or indirectly via some other `#include`), the compiler has no idea `std::vector` exists in the first place." The answer to why some code samples work without the include is that they included some other header which in turn includes `<vector>`. If they don't, then there is no definition of `std::vector`, and the code fails with undefined types. It must be included, but that doesn't mean you included it directly (that said, you should, to avoid header changes breaking compilation).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That's a great explanation. Put it in the answer please :D

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't you have to include < vector > if you already include using
>   namespace std

Take a look at this url:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

There are more than 100 header files available for your use.

IMHO, the confusion you are experiencing is that these same 100+ header are ALSO available for the header authors, and they also have access to headers not usually published in the standard.  The result is that, for instance, when you or I include < stringstream >, some indirect part of that include might also 'pull-in' < string >.

I recommend you do not put "using namespace std" in your code.  It's use did not intentionally cause the 'hidden / indirect' include of < vector >, and maybe won't on the next implementation.

I'm on g++v7.3.  I'll soon be upgrading to current g++ (I think 9.x?)  You can not rely on < vector > being included unless you explicitly include it.

> this works for me, but I want to understand why this one works and the
>   other one doesn't.

Just luck ... I think bad, if you start multiple bad habits because of it.

---

If your compiler supports -std=c++17 or better, it has a new feature I like.  The new feature allows me to, immediately after the header include, specify which function in that library I specifically need.  It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::flush,
      std::hex, std::dec, std::cin;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw, std::setfill;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;

#include <thread>
using std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

---

Your own libraries can be handled similarly:

```
#ifndef                 DTB_ENG_FORMAT_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_eng_format.hh"
using DTB::EngFormat_t;
#endif

#ifndef                 DTB_PPLSEM_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_pplsem.hh"
using DTB::PPLSem_t;
#endif

#ifndef                 DTB_ENG_FORMAT_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_eng_format.hh"
#endif

#ifndef                 DTB_ASSERT_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_assert.hh"
#endif
```

I try to keep track of a smalle set of these, and collect them in a file.  I use the bigger lists when I am starting a new effort, and trivially remove the 'unused' functions (when I want to post my efforts).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. In own VS setup there's `<filesystem>` which pulls in `<vector>`, where the risk of not including `<vector>` comes at the cost of hoping it won't be pulled from `<filesystem>` during the lifetime of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does dont you have to #include, if you already include using name space std?

You have to include `<vector>` only if you use the declarations from that header. Otherwise you don't need to include it. You don't ever *need* `using namespace std;`.

> don't quite seem to understand why if you write
>
> ```
> std:vector<int> - //blah, a vector is created.
> ```
>
> However, in some cases you need to write
>
> ```
> #include <vector> //to include vector library
> ```

You **always** have to include `<vector>` if you create `std:vector<int>` objects.

> Does the standard library where we usually write "using namespace std" - already include the vector library?

No, The standard library doesn't use `using namespace std;`. If it did, that would invalidate the whole point of using the `std` namespace.

> When I remove the definition file #include, then the computer cannot recognize my vector variables.

This is because you cannot declare a variable of a type that hasn't been defined. The definition of `std::vector` is in `<vector>`

Answer (score 0):

`#include <some_file>` just replaces the `#include` directive with the contents of the file "some_file".

In the case of `#include <vector>`, the file "vector" contains the definition of the class template `vector` in the `std` namespace.  To declare an instance of a class, that class's definition must be visible to the compiler, so to declare `std::vector<int> foo` you must `#include <vector>`, either directly or indirectly by `#include`ing another file that `#include`s it.

So why do some code samples have to `#include <vector>` and others don't?  Well, they all do.  Some may not `#include` it explicitly, but they must `#include` another file that does `#include <vector>`.

Of course, in many example snippets people will simply omit the `#include`s for brevity.  The code won't compile without the proper `#include`s, but they make the code longer and may distract from the point the author is trying to make.

---

The statement `using namespace std;` just tells the compiler that it should search the `std` namespace for any unqualified names it can't find in the current namespace.  That means that the compiler can find the `vector` class by both the names `vector` and `std::vector`.

Comment: This only answers half the question clearly, and only hints at the answer to the other half. Why don't the other code samples need the include?

Answer (score 0):

First, `std:vector<int> - //blah, a vector is created.` won't compile because you used a single colon `:` which means that `std` here is a `label` declaration. and a label name cannot be `vector<int>`. So I guess you meant: `std::vector<int>`.

Second, As you may know `vector`, `iostream`,... are library types defined in headers `<vector>`, `<iotream>` respectively... To use these types you must include these headers first either directly or indirectly.

`namespace std` in C++ is a grouping of identifiers that is used to reduce the possibility of naming collisions. In modern C++, all of the functionality in the C++ standard library is now defined inside namespace std (short for standard).

Look for example at `std::cout`; this identifier is declared in namespace `std` whose type is `ostream`. So to you must include `iostream` first so that the compile can see what `ostream` object is and then tell the compiler where this object is declared? `in namespace std`. So including only `iostream` is not sufficient thus you either add the whole content of namespace `std` in which `cout` is declared, or just tell the compiler explicitly where `cout` is declared through fully qualifying it:

```
#include <iostream> // contains output/input library types definitions
using std::cout; // ok add only cout definition to the program not the whole content of std.
using namespace std; // contains cout, cin, vector....
```

Answer (score -1):

Vectors are part of the C++ STL, yes, but you need to include the `<vector>` header file to be able to use it. It's the same reason why you need to `#include <string>` if you want to use STL strings. After you include these headers, you need to use the `std::` namespace identifier before declaring a vector or string, so that the compiler knows that what you're declaring is part of the C++ STL and not built-in to "base" C or C++.

Somewhat basically, what `using namespace std` does is give you the ability to drop the `std::` qualifier before your `string` or `vector` or whatever. This isn't recommended, [here's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/) an article briefly explaining why you shouldn't be using it. Instead, if you want to clean up your code and don't want to type `std::` every time you want to print to the console, then consider importing single identifiers, for example `using namespace std::cout` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only answers half the question. Why don't the other code samples need the include?

Comment: As has been mentioned in other answers, other people's code could be including headers that have vectors, but there are no guarantees

Comment: By Sergey Zubkov  from  https://www.quora.com/In-C-what-is-stl-and-std-How-are-they-different : 
 “STL” (“standard template library”) was the name of a Hewlett-Packard’s C++ library in the early 1990s. It was hugely influential in the development of the C++ standard library in 1998, and that was its undoing: HP saw no need to maintain STL, it spend over a decade abandoned on SGI’s website, and is now gone."   
....Your conforming compiler (such as g++ 9.2.1 on Lubuntu 19.10) comes with the "C++ standard library" and you should be using it (not the abandoned STL).  i.e. 'vector' is included.